# Reading lines in a file and avoiding lines with # with Bash

Tags: bash, loops, comments

I tried this:

```
file="myfile"
while read -r line
do
    [[ $line = \#* ]] && continue
    "address=\$line\127.0.0.1"
done < "$file"
```

This code doesn't avoid the lines that begin with comments. Even if I don't have any comments, `dnsmasq` tells that there are errors.

Its going to be a `dnsmasq` conf file, and it will read and insert domain names like so: `address=\mydomain.com\127.0.0.1`.

---

## EDIT:1

Input file:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
#domain4.com
domain5.com
```

Output should be:

```
address=/domain1.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain2.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain3.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain5.com/127.0.0.1
```

I will drop the script in */etc/dnsmasq.d/* directory so that [dnsmaq.conf](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq.conf.example) can  process it when `dnsmasq` is started.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's safer to use `[[ "$line" = "\#*" ]]`

Btw, `address="\\${line}\\127.0.0.1"`

**UPD**:

If I've understand you right you need to change every uncommented domains to `address=\domain\127.0.0.1`. It could be done fast and easy with `sed`, there is no need in bash-program.

```
$> cat ./text
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
#domain4.com
domain5.com

$> sed -r -e 's/(^[^#]*$)/address=\/\1\/127.0.0.1/g' ./text2
address=/domain1.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain2.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain3.com/127.0.0.1
#domain4.com
address=/domain5.com/127.0.0.1
```

If you need to remove commented lines, sed can do it too with `/matched_line/d`

```
$> sed -r -e 's/(^[^#]*$)/address=\/\1\/127.0.0.1/g; /^#.*$/d' ./text2 
address=/domain1.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain2.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain3.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain5.com/127.0.0.1
```

**UPD2**: if you want to do all that stuff inside the bash script, here is your code modification:

```
file="./text2"
while read -r line; do
    [[ "$line" =~ ^#.*$ ]] && continue
    echo "address=/${line}/127.0.0.1"
done < "$file"
```

And it's output:

```
address=/domain1.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain2.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain3.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain5.com/127.0.0.1
```

Comment: `address=` is not a variable. Its a string that should get repeated in all the lines.

Comment: What you mean `repeated`? You want to replace all lines like #* with `address=\${line}\127.0.0.1`?

Comment: It will be great if you show file that you have and show file that you want.

Comment: I couldn't get dnsmasq to parse the script by adding the link to the script in dnsmasq.conf. But I made the init file of dnsmasq to execute the script and added the link to the file that was got as an output in dnsmasq.conf. And it worked.

Comment: The comment matching should be `[[ "$line" = "#"* ]]`. There may be some discrepancy between systems / versions.

Comment: what if a comment line with leading spaces "      #..." ?

Comment: The while read method here is slower if you got multi white spaces. Use answer from @Keith Thompson for faster result. For explicit subshell use the one commented from JGurtz

Answer (score 49):

To skip lines *starting* with `#`:

```
grep -v '^#' myfile | while read -r file ; do
    ...
done
```

Modify the `grep` command as needed to, for example, skip lines starting with whitespace and a `#` character.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but maybe they prefer the explicit subshell over implicit one? Such as: `while IFS= read -r TI; do echo "${TI}"; done < <(grep -v '#' ./items)`

Comment: This one is faster than the original answer. Because while read the whole file and do grep is slower.

Answer (score 9):

Comment lines can and often do begin with whitespace. Here's a bash native regex solution that handles any preceeding whitespace;

```
while read line; do
  [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*# ]] && continue
  ...work with valid line...
done
```

Comment: I tested this under **GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)** with comments having zero, one or two leading spaces and/or tabs.  I'm not sure why, but using `[[ "$line" =~ ^# ]] && continue` worked the same.

Comment: Digging deeper, `while IFS= read line` does not strip surrounding white-space from the line being read.

Answer (score 7):

```
[ "${line:0:1}" = "#" ] && continue
```

This takes the string, gets the substring at [offset 0, length 1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
"${line:0:1}"
```

and checks if it is equal to `#`

```
= "#"
```

and continues looping if so

```
&& continue
```

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: Thanks for this, I found this very easy to follow and well explained and without invoking additional complexity (sed, awk and that weird creepy syntax that starts with ^)

Answer (score 5):

Only one working for me was:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read line
do  
    if [[ "$line" =~ \#.* ]];then
        logDebug "comment line:$line"
    else
        logDebug "normal line:$line"
    fi
done < myFile
```

Answer (score 3):

You can filter with `awk`:

```
awk '!/^#/{print"address=/"$0"/127.0.0.1"}' file
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please?

Comment: First it says not to print the line that starts with number sign and then add on either side of original text, $0, what was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

This could also be accomplished with 1 `sed` command:

```
file="myfile"

sed -i".backup" 's/^#.*$//' $file
```

This will modify the file in-place (creating a backup copy first), removing all lines starting with a `#`.

Answer (score 1):

It has 3 parts. Please read each to understand clearly

1. To remove # line ----- `awk -F'#' '{print $1}' t.txt`
2. To remove a blank line created by #  ----  `awk 'NF > 0'`
3. To print in required format.  ------`awk '{print "address=/"$0"/127.0.0.1"}'`

So Total Script Needed is,

```
**awk -F'#' '{print $1}' t.txt | awk 'NF > 0' | awk '{print "address=/"$0"/127.0.0.1"}'**
```

Output :

```
address=/domain1.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain2.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain3.com/127.0.0.1
address=/domain5.com/127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ if ($0 !~ /^#/){printf "address=/%s/127.0.0.1 \n",$0}}' <your_input_file>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try

```
[[ "$line"~="#.*" ]] && continue
```

Check the `~` in operand!

Comment: it should be '=~' not '~='